# Real path of file string pathlib

Tags: python, pathlib

I've been searching for what seems like hours for how to get a real path in string format from a `pathlib.PosixPath` using pathlib.

The only solution I can find is this:

```
str(myPathObject.resolve())
```

This seems messy.  Am I missing something or is this only solution that exists?

Edit:

To clarify, this is giving me a filepath `/opt/digglerz/projects` of type string, which is what i want.  This seems a long way to do this, is there no better way?

Comment: What you are getting as output ans what you expecting? Please clarify.

Comment: @AmazingThingsAroundYou done

Comment: How is `str(myPathObject.resolve())` "long" or "messy"?

Comment: Still I am unable to get what you are looking for. Why do you think the above answer is messy or long process?

Answer (score 3):

`resolve()` is a good idea, but the literal casting with `str` indeed seems a bit messy. I would go with built-in methods like `as_posix()` or `as_uri()` depending on what you want.

Understand that the concept of "real path" as you call it may be different in different situations and on different platforms.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/pathlib.py#L713) reveals that `as_posix()` just returns `str(self).replace(f.sep, '/')`.

Comment: Why would you use `as_posix()` to convert a path to string? If you don't want a posix path, don't use `as_posix()`. Just use `str`.

Answer (score 1):

Since 3.6 the correct way to convert a Path object back into a string seems to be:

```
os.fspath(path)
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.fspath